# Get project commits using node-gitlab api

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, gitlab-api

Using node-gitlab API in NodeJS application, how can i get a project's list of commits.
I could get the list of projects using:

```
router.get('/projects', function(req, res, next) {
    gitlab.projects.all(function(projects) {
    res.json(projects);
    console.log(projects);
  });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to do it

```
gitlab.projects.repository.listCommits(projectId,function(commits) {
```

});

Answer (score 0):

it's not documented in the api, but i found it in the repository.js file of the package:

`gitlab.repository.getCommits(id, ref_name)`

id: projectId,

ref_name: name of a repository branch or tag or if not given the default branch